# All series on a given axis must be of the same data type when generating JSON code with python

Tags: python, json, charts

I am creating a Chart using the Gooogle Chart API. I am generating the JSON string using Python to extract data from my database. I want to create a chart with multiple series aggregated by the column 'Category' and the below is what I am using as my schema.

```
  description = {"category": ("string", "Category"), "date": ("string", "Date"), "noOfQuotations": ("number", "Frequency")}
```

To generate the data, I do:

```
data = []
for row in vals:
  d = {"category":row[0], "date":row[1], "noOfQuotations": int(row[2])}
  data.append(d)
```

I then create the datatable.

```
data_table = gviz_api.DataTable(description)
data_table.LoadData(data)
```

To get JSON string I do:

```
json = data_table.ToJSon(columns_order=("category", "date", "noOfQuotations"),
                       order_by=("category"))
```

I then pass the output code from the python script into the HTML code below

```
<html>
<head>
<!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

           google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(
    /PASTING CODE HERE TEMPORARILY/
  );

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

However I get the below error: 
All series on a given axis must be of the same data type